# How to leave input at the end of a div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

Well, guys, I want to leave my input and my button at the end of the div, but I can't do this at all, I'm trying to chat and I need to stylize some things yet so don't mind the design so much, look how it is now:

[image]

**Problem:**

Guys I don't know if you can see the input anymore and the button is not at the end of the div and when I scroll the div together because it has a `fixed` position but the input and the button remains in the same place, that is, it doesn’t stay in the  end of the div, I want it to be at the bottom of the div.

**My code:**

**Html:**

```
<div class="chat">
 <div class="ul" id="messages"></div>
 <div class="send">
  <input class="text" autofocus="" id="menssagem" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Cloud está em apuros!">
  <button class="btn" id="enviar_menssagem">Send</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Css:**

```
@keyframes animationButton  {  
 0%{                                              
  filter:hue-rotate(0deg);                       
 }
 100%{
  filter:hue-rotate(360deg);
 }                                              
}

.chat{
display:block;
position:fixed;
top:0;
width:100%;
height:100vh;
background:#363636;
z-index:1;
}

.send {
width:100%;
height:20%;
background:#373737;
overflow:hidden;
}

.send .text {
float:left;
width:75%;
height:50px;
border: double 2px transparent;
border-radius:7px;
background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top left, red,green, yellow, blue);
background-origin: border-box;
background-clip: content-box, border-box;
animation:animationButton .5s infinite;
}
```

**Summary:**
You can change the background of the `send` div to be able to see it better, if you change the background to a different color you will see that the input and the Button are not at the end of the `send` div and I want the input and the  Button is at the end of the div send, but I need my `chat` div to still have a fixed position because I need to ensure that it doesn't matter if the person scrolls the elements will scroll with the page and also that  the div will occupy 100% of the screen, notice that using position fixed even when I scroll the div still occupies 100% of the screen, I need this to remain so

> I would like to say that I am Brazilian and my English is not so good, and I cannot ask questions in the Portuguese stack overflow, so the names of the html ids and classes are in English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using the combination of the `grid` and the `flex` layout.

```css
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.chat {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: calc(100vh - 50px) 50px;
}

.send{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  column-gap: 1rem;
}

.send input{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
  <div class="ul" id="messages"></div>
  <div class="send">
    <input class="text" autofocus="" id="menssagem" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Cloud está em apuros!">
    <button class="btn" id="enviar_menssagem">Send</button>
  </div>
</div>
```